# Add Some Value to index-0 in Array before explode function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, push, explode, array-push

I have a code similar to

```
$results = array();
array_push($results, $term);
//after a few more lines
$results=explode(",", $resutl_string[1]);
```

but necessarily overwrite `index 0` and I am unable to save `$term` on `index 0`, although I can successfully push `$term` at the end,

wondering for some clue or help to put my `$term` at `index 0`

thanks in advance

Comment: I can't entirely understand what you're asking, but is something like [array_unshift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) what you're after?

Comment: yeah, exactly, thanks, please put that as an answer

Comment: Also, this might have considerable overhead for larger arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the array to be the term plus the current contents, you can use this:

```
array_unshift($term, $results);
```